# Why i cant see trought while i am drawing

Tags: grease-pencil

In Greasepencil, when i draw , my previous draw that is with transparency at 50% i wont show me the bottom reference image. I am drawing and this happends. I dont know how to revert this. I am using the stable 2.80.

[grease pencil problem in 2.8](https://youtu.be/X9Rc1_MAWLg)